# Tap device blocking all communication on my VirtualBox host machine

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm trying to create a user space network stack for learning purposes.

What I'm trying to do is to set up a tap device on my VirtualBox machine with Windows 10 host.
The VirtualBox is running Ubuntu 16.04 on a bridged network.

The way I'm setting up the tap device is by creating a tap in `/dev/net`:

```
sudo mknod /dev/net/tap c 10 200
```

My program is running `tun_alloc`:

```
/*
 * Taken from Kernel Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt
 */

int tun_alloc(char *dev)
{
    struct ifreq ifr;
    int fd, err;

    /* Arguments taken by the function:
     *
     * char *dev: the name of an interface (or '\0'). MUST have enough
     *   space to hold the interface name if '\0' is passed
     * int flags: interface flags (eg, IFF_TUN etc.)
     */

    /* open the clone device */
    if ((fd = open("/dev/net/tap", O_RDWR)) < 0)
    {
        printf("Cannot open TUN/TAP dev\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    /* preparation of the struct ifr, of type "struct ifreq" */
    memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));

    /* Flags: IFF_TUN   - TUN device (no Ethernet headers)
     *        IFF_TAP   - TAP device
     *
     *        IFF_NO_PI - Do not provide packet information
     */
    ifr.ifr_flags = IFF_TAP | IFF_NO_PI;
    if (*dev)
    {
        /* if a device name was specified, put it in the structure; otherwise,
         * the kernel will try to allocate the "next" device of the
         * specified type */
        strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, dev, IFNAMSIZ);
    }

    /* try to create the device */
    if ((err = ioctl(fd, TUNSETIFF, (void *)&ifr)) < 0)
    {
        printf("ERR: Could not ioctl tun: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        close(fd);
        return err;
    }

    /* if the operation was successful, write back the name of the
     * interface to the variable "dev", so the caller can know
     * it. Note that the caller MUST reserve space in *dev (see calling
     * code below) */
    strcpy(dev, ifr.ifr_name);

    /* this is the special file descriptor that the caller will use to talk
     * with the virtual interface */
    return fd;
}
```

And then runs the following shell commands (from program):

```
ip link set dev tap0 up
ip route add dev tap0 192.168.1.0/24
ip address add dev tap0 local 192.168.1.21
```

When I run this, my `ifconfig` shows:

```
enp0s3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:2f:ba:f8  
          inet addr:192.168.1.36  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::445b:f137:4390:8b40/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:149 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1239 (1.2 KB)  TX bytes:24836 (24.8 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:68 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:68 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5351 (5.3 KB)  TX bytes:5351 (5.3 KB)

tap0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e2:c8:48:94:af:9c  
          inet addr:192.168.1.21  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: fe80::e0c8:48ff:fe94:af9c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:51 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:42 (42.0 B)  TX bytes:6078 (6.0 KB)
```

When I don't run the program and don't have the tap0 interface, I can ping to my host machine, and it can ping me.

But when I run this program, and my tap device is up, I suddenly lose communication to my host.
Furthermore, when I ping from the host to my VM, I don't see any packets read by the tunnel, and in fact when check out the ARP table of my Windows host, I see that also the `enp0s3` interface MAC address was deleted from this ARP table.

Just to be clear, I do see other packets received on the tap device, just not from outside my host.

This is what I see when I test ARP requests from inside my host machine:

```
arping -I tap0 192.168.1.21
ARPING 192.168.1.21 from 192.168.1.21 tap0
Unicast reply from 192.168.1.21 [00:0C:29:6D:50:25]  0.545ms
Unicast reply from 192.168.1.21 [00:0C:29:6D:50:25]  0.733ms
```

Now my questions are these:

1. Why, when running my tap device, I don't see any packets coming from outside?
2. Why I cant ping my other (enp0s3) interface as well? what is the relation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have overlapping LAN segments: Both `enp0s3` and `tap0` have 192.168.1.0/24. So this can't work.

Give your `tap0` interface a non-overlapping range instead, e.g. 192.168.2.0/24.

And if you want to create your own network stack, I suggest reading up on LAN segments, broadcast domains, and *why* they all must be different on different network adapters.

And if you want to learn networking, I also suggest playing around with network namespace and virtual ethernet pairs first. This way you'll be able to set up your own "simulated" network, and get hands on experience in network. That will writing your own network stack a lot easier. There are even GUIs that do set up such networks for you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will check it out

Comment: If I create another device, shouldn't my windows machine create an ARP request that will reach to this device? why should the layer 3 address even matter? I did some testing, and if I give my tap0 device an address of 192.168.0.21 and configure the route tables of my linux and windows, I can actually ping from windows to 192.168.0.21, but when I tcpdump on tap0 I dont see any packets received, only on enp0s3.

Comment: Unless you use *VirtualBox networking* to create the device (which you didn't), neither VirtualBox nor Windows knows anything about it at all. A tap device is one end of a connection that appears to the Linux OS as a network interface, you must handle the other end inside the program that calls `tun_alloc`. And this program doesn't know anything about the host Windows OS, either, so you can implement your own network stack in it, but you can't connect to Windows this way.

Comment: Then why when I configure the route table in windows to send 192.168.0.* packets to 192.168.1.36 and then ping 192.168.0.21 I get a reply? Who is sending the reply back? enp0s3?

Comment: The only connection between Windows and the guest OS is by Virtualbox networking, which simulates an ethernet card for enp0s3. Yes, Linux will reply for packets with a destination address of any of the local interfaces, even if they are not coming in on the interface with this particular address (*Weak End System Model*, see e.g. RFC 1122). For you tap interface, the proper way to think about is "it will work the same, no matter if it runs on the guest OS in Virtualbox, or on a real Linux host".